How to replace blank/null with 0 in Power BI
i tried to create a report using matrix card. but it gives a blank/null if there is no record.
enter image description here
when i try to add NewMeasure = COALESCE(sum('Income Statement P&L'[TotCost]),0), all row displays in every sub hierarchy.
